# Calculate SSE using R output

Tags: r, regression

I'm confused about how to manually calculate SSE using R output. I'm thinking about using residual standard error and maybe the relationship between SSE, SSR and SSTO, but not sure what's next.

My R output is attached below:

[image: R output]

Answer (score 0):

There is a relationship between the sum of the squared residuals (what you call SSE) and what R calls “residual standard error” (what I’ll call $RMSE$).

$$
RMSE =\sqrt{\dfrac{SSE}{n-p}}\\\iff\\SSE=
RMSE^2\times (n-p)
$$

That $n-p$ term is the sample size minus the number of estimated regression parameters, and it is called the “degrees of freedom”.

You have an $RMSE=9.528$ on $227$ degrees of freedom. Thus:

$$
SSE =9.528^2\times 227
$$

This does not quite match the answer you cite as the correct answer, but that is due to R rounding the printout. If you extract the residual standard error from the linear model output, your answer should match.

Comment: thank you for your reply but the answer should be 20609.5 by running formula in R, which doesn't match with your answer:(

Comment: Ohhhhhhh I know, the residual standard error is equal to square root of MSE, thus SSE equals to (9.528^2)*227! Thanks Dave!

Comment: @NingzeXia Edited. To get the exact answer you have as the correct answer, you need to carry more decimal points than the printout does. This can be done by extracting the exact number. The documentation will say how to do that: `str(summary(lm(…))) `.